# Understand the definition of Lebesgue measure from exterior measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am doing some independent reading about measure theory. I use the textbook "Real Analysis, Measure Theory, Integration, & Hilbert Spaces" by Elias M. Stein & Rami Shakarchi. I did some search and didn't find any similar question regarding this aspect.

In section 1.2, the book talks about properties of the exterior measure. And Observation 3 states

> If *E* $\subset \mathbb{R}^d$, then $m_{*}(E)= \inf m_{*}(O)$, where the infimum is taken over all open sets $O$ containing $E$.

And in section 1.3, the book begins to introduce the definition of Lebesgue measure with the following

> A subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$ is **Lebesgue measurable** or simply **measurable**, if for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an open set $O$ with $E \subset O$ and $m_{*}(O-E)\leq \epsilon$

This should be compared to Observation 3, which holds for *all* sets $E$.

Here is my question, I don't get the difference between those two statements. Would someone please explain it to me? How does the latter one have more restrictions on the subset $E$? Thank you in advance.

Comment: For a Lebesgue measurable set, we need the outer measure of $E$ to be equal to the inner measure of $E$.  The first definition  tells you only the outer measure of $E$, and nothing about the inner measure.  The second definition tells you the outer and inner measure differ by at most $\epsilon$.

Comment: An important distinction is that the exterior measure is defined for all subsets of $\mathbb R^d$, but it turns out that only some subsets of $\mathbb R^d$ satisfy the criterion for Lebesgue measurability, which roughly speaking ensures that their exterior measure is well behaved.

Comment: @GEdgar I didn't get how the second definition is related to the inner measure. Doesn't the definition still focus on the possible open set containing E?

Comment: @Bungo That's how I interpret as well, but I feel it is somehow vague. Would you mind elaborating the difference from the specific preconditions? Is it possible that the latter holds for measurability because we are directly comparing exterior measure to make two sets as close as possible? (I may not express myself clearly, hopefully you can understand my question.)

Comment: The exterior measure is defined on all subsets of $\mathbb R^d$,as was pointed out, but if one wants the measure to satisfy some "reasonable" conditions, then one must restrict it to a certain $\sigma $-algebra of sets. The restriction of the outer measure to this algebra is by definition, the Lesbegue measure. It then turns out that the second statement in the OP's post follows from this. That is, once the outer measure is defined, and the $\sigma$-algebra found, the "definition" of lebesgue measureablity the OP refers to is in fact a consequence.